# How accurate / up-to-date is the depends field in .tlpobj

Tags: texlive, tlmgr, dependencies

Information about the dependencies of packages can be viewed by using `tlmgr --data "name,depends" info` to get a list of all packages and their dependencies. I'm guessing this shows the information that authors specify in [DEPENDS.TXT](https://www.tug.org/texlive/pkgcontrib.html#deps).

Now many of the packages that get listed using the above command have no `depends` info at all. For those that do, I'm wondering to what extent the listed dependencies reflect the actual dependencies of the package.

One example where I've noticed they don't (seem to) reflect the actual dependencies is with `todonotes`: tlmgr lists `xcolor:tools:xkeyval:pgf` as dependencies, but in todonotes.sty it says this:

```
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
\RequirePackage{xkeyval}
\RequirePackage{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\RequirePackage{calc}
```

As you can see, the file requires ifthen which isn't listed by tlmgr. Can this be explained by something I overlooked, or is what tlmgr lists as dependencies simply outdated?

If tlmgr's information about dependencies is outdated, are there any other sources that could be consulted for getting the dependencies of a package? I've seen some packages listing them in the documentation pdf on CTAN, but very rarely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dependency information in TeX Live is at best partial: it's not required for the set up, and it's only listed when a package is absolutely required. Moreover, it lists *TeX Live* packages not *(La)TeX*. You also need to remember that some stuff is 'automatically required'. For example, `ifthen` is part of the core LaTeX `tools` bundle, and that is regarded by the LaTeX team as a required part of LaTeX. So *any* LaTeX installation should have `tool`, and thus `ifthen`: there is no need to list it as a dependency for TeX Live, since a user installing `latex-base` but not `latex-tools` is creating a 'broken' LaTeX set up from the get-go.

You also have to remember that some packages will be dependencies of others, so for example `tikz` requires `xcolor`, so if one is using `tikz`, it's not necessary to list `xcolor` as a dependency.

At best, therefore, the dependencies list is a guide.

---

If you want to be sure about TeX Live package dependencies, create a virtual machine and do a step-by-step install of packages starting from a scheme you are happy with (I'd go with `infra-only` for complete control).

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming my suspicions. Also, the tip with using a VM for testing it out seems like a smart approach, I will do that.